# Where does Civi store membership and membership signup info?

Tags: civimember, import, export

We are moving to a new site, and when I tried to import our entire current Civi MySQL database to the new site, I had problems.

So I have created a fresh database on the new site and want to try importing things bit-by-bit, starting with memberships.  We have a membership signup page as well as info about past signups.

Can anyone tell me which tables from the current database I need to import to the new site? Any other advice/warnings would be welcome, too!

I am not able to get into the Civi interface (e.g. contributions, events, administer) on the current site, but can access the Civi database. So I want to do this just by exporting and importing from/to the databases.

(I can access Civi and WordPress files on both sites via FTP if that's helpful.)

Both sites are WordPress 4.9.1 and Civi 4.7.29.

Old site is at 1and1, new site at civihosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing to do is to do a complete dump of your old database and import it into a fresh database on your new server. Then use that for your new Civi install. Importing piece by piece creates problems because there is too much data that is reliant on other tables.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but had problems.  I guess I'll just reconstruct the membership page in the new environment.

Comment: Actually, I just heard from civihosting, and they are going to try to fix the errors and do the import for me.  By the way, thank you for waving me off a path that would have led to trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jenni, trying to do this table for table makes it extremely complicated and probably undoable. So I would do a `mysqldump` to dump the source database and restore it on the new site.

There are some guidelines here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/